# Restoring only some tables into Heroku Postgres via heroku pgbackups:restore

Tags: postgresql, heroku, psql, heroku-postgres

According to the [heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export), the following command restores a pg_dump into a Heroku Postgres Database:

```
heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/me/items/3H0q/mydb.dump'
```

However, is there a way to restore only some tables to the database? I tried using `\copy` from a `psql` terminal using `heroku pg:psql`, but it is WAY slower that restore.

I'm looking for a way to actually run `pg_restore -t my_table` on heroku, for example.

Also, `taps`has never worked for me, and it is not the recommended way to go in ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: This solution may be relevant to some people: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42433414/heroku-database-restore-issue/42435490#42435490

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run pg_restore locally connected to your Heroku provided Postgres instance. Get you db credentials from

```
heroku config
```

From the database_url key and pass them into pg_restore locally as options. Then you should also be able to use the -t switch to restore your specific table.

Comment: Do you mean `heroku pg:credentials DATABASE_URL`?

Comment: I ran pgbackups:restore (fore the whole db) and the compared to pg_restore locally as you suggested and it was doing OK but it took much longer. 5 minutes vs. an hour. Is there a solution which runs on heroku? I can't wait that long (DB has > 5M rows.)