# Heroku database restore issue

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

Have gone through different solutions available on `stackoverflow`and also on different forums. But none addresses the precise problem.

> As per the documentation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

I have the `dump` file created from my local database, with this command:

```
pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U postgres dss_iaya>dss_iaya_db_dump1.dump
```

Then as per documentation, uploaded to a server with public access URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iaya-664f3.appspot.com/o/dss_iaya_db_dump1.dump?alt=media&token=06167d04-1e98-4e4b-b0e0-9d83a86dd167

Now when I try to restore on `Heroku` as per its documentation syntax `heroku pg:backups:restore [BACKUP] [DATABASE] --app APP` using following command, it returns error message when restoring.

```
heroku pg:backups:restore  --app heroku-postgres-*** 'https://firebasestorage.***/dss_iaya_db_dump1.dump?alt=media&token=***' 'postgres://quesu***:I***@ec2-54-***.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/d3n***k0'
```

> I have used *** for security purpose only, as can not mention full credentials. But I believe one can understand the whole syntax.

When I restore same `.dump` file on a newly created local database it works without any issues and creates/restores the whole database with tables and data.

[image: Command console screen]

[image: Info log]

Comment: what `heroku pg:backups:info r006` shows?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the solution, actually two things were wrong in my case.

One, the uploaded `.dump` file was not well readable/usable by the `heroku`.

Two, the `heroku postgresql DB` complete URL was not required to be provided.

> So, the right way that worked for me was that the uploaded file should be accessible **without any token and also without any virtual/indirect path, etc. The URL to the file should point to the file directly**. *In my questioned problem, I was using `firebase` to host my DB file temporarily to do the `heroku` operation. And `firebase` was not giving direct URL to the uploaded physical file*.

```
heroku pg:backups:restore  --app heroku-postgres-f3*** 'https://www.h***.com/dss_iaya_db_dump2.dump' DATABASE_URL
```

After typing this command, I was asked to retype the `heroku` app name just to confirm the operation. Once done, everything worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

In logs you see dump size: **0 Bytes**. Also you see **aborting** and **403**, 
so if you check your file: https://llfirebasestorage.googleapis.com/vo/b/iaya-664f3.appspot.com/0/dss_iaya_db_dump1.dump?a1t=media

you get:

> ```
> 404. That’s an error.
>
> The requested URL /vo/b/iaya-664f3.appspot.com/0/dss_iaya_db_dump1.dump was not found on
> ```
>
> this server. That’s all we know.

Comment: Thanks, this points to the problem area direction correctly. Though, I just posted the solution to the problem a while ago. Love your swift response :)